# Pass List of UUID to django endpoint url as param

Tags: django, api, view

I have this code

```
#VIEWS
def report_pdf(request, queryset):
   if request.method == "GET":
       trans = Transaction.objects.filter(id__in=queryset)
    return something

#URLS
path("pdf/<uuid:queryset>", views.report_pdf, name="get_pdf")

#FRONT END
const handlePDFDownload = (ids) => {
    const body = ids
    axios.get(`/calc/pdf/`,body , { 
        responseType: 'blob',
    }).then(res => {
        fileDownload(res.data, 'filename.zip');
        console.log(res, 'downloading');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
 }
```

Now from my frontend react iam sending a `get` request to this `endpoint` with a `list of UUID` values.
I cant find a way to access that list in my view coming from frontend.

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you pass the uuids as query params to the url as

> ../pdf?queryset=<uuids here>

then get the list in your view as

> queryset = request.GET.get('queryset')

and then use `queryset` further in view.

Comment: This works fine, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending list of uuid's from frontend but in your urls expects one uuid so that you need to change it like this:

urls.py:

```
path("pdf/", views.report_pdf, name="get_pdf")
```

views.py:

```
def report_pdf(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
       uuid_list = request.GET.getlist("queryset[]")
       trans = Transaction.objects.filter(id__in=uuid_list)
    return something
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still i cant access the ids at view, i updated my question to include the fronend code

Comment: In react you have `/calc/podf/` but in urls your have `pdf` is `calc` an app name in which `report_pdf` view is ? If yes then either change `podf` to `pdf` in react or `pdf` to `podf` in urls.py.

Comment: that is not the case i have ` `calc/podf/queryset=${id}` ` in react and in django url `path("podf/", views.report_pdf, name="get_pdf") ` and yes `calc` is the app name. knowing that if i change `queryset` from a list in react and add normal int value, i can access it with a param from django view

Comment: But the question was accessing list in django not a single id ? How is that accepted answer helping in that case ?

Comment: I can now access the list, but i get the list as a string, and i converted the string to list again in django.